# Proof lower level sets of continuous strictly convex function are closed

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization

I need to prove that the following set:
$$\mathcal L:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \, : \, f(x) \leq f(x_0) \}$$
which apparently is called lower level set, is compact. I've already proved boundedness and I just need to show closeness.

The function $f$ is twice continuously differentiable on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and so it is continuous everywhere.

I am looking for a "simple" proof, i.e. one that uses the notion of continuity and the notion of closeness/openness, NOT the notion of semi-continuity, which is used in every single proof I've found.

**My Attempt**

$f$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ means that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$\forall \epsilon >0, \, \exists \delta > 0 \, \forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n: ||x - y|| < \delta \Longrightarrow ||f(x)-f(y)||< \epsilon$$
On the other hand, $\mathcal L$ is closed means that its complement wrt $\mathbb{R}^n$ is open, that is:
$$\forall x\in\bar{\mathcal{L}}, \exists \epsilon > 0 \, \forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n \, : \, ||x - y||<\epsilon \Longrightarrow y\in \bar{\mathcal{L}}$$

Now using continuity we know:
$$||x-y|| < \delta \Longrightarrow ||f(x)-f(y)||<\epsilon \Longrightarrow -\epsilon < f(x) - f(y) < \epsilon$$
And so $\Longrightarrow f(y)-\epsilon < f(x) < \epsilon+f(y)$. How do I continue? Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

If we define 
$$
g(x)=f(x)-f(x_0)
$$
a continuous function, the set is 
$$
g^{-1}((-\infty,0])
$$
the preimage of a closed set under a continuous map.

If you are wedded to epsilon's and delta's, then pick $x\in \mathcal{L}^c$, then 
$$
g(x)>0
$$
and for $\epsilon=\frac{g(x)}{2}$, we have for some $\delta>0$ corresponding to this $\epsilon$, 
$$
g(y)>0
$$
for all $y\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$. So $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset \mathcal{L}^c$.

Comment: Can you please expand a little bit more? It seems interesting but I’m struggling to understand

Comment: I added a solution using the epsilon-delta definition of continuity. In general in topology, a continuous function is one which has the property that preimages of open sets are open. This then implies that preimages of closed sets are closed.